# create_wrapper command not found

Tags: perl, wrapper, openembedded

I am trying to compile "perl" and "perl-native" using OpenEmbedded recipes. In my Linux machine, I have perl 5.8.8 installed. When I run "bitbake perl-native" it results in an error saying "create_wrapper command not found".

I came across this webpage
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man3/Bio::Tools::Run::Phylo::Hyphy::Base.3pm.html

which shows the command. But I'm not sure how to incorporate it in my build framework.

Comment: The page you found is unrelated to the problem you're having; it's just another thing that coincidentally has the same name. The problem is with the OE recipe, and you should ask the maintainers of perl in OE for advice.

Comment: The command(create_wrapper) is used by the recipe and so the recipe expects it to be present in my linux machine. But it ain't. I'm trying to find out how to make it available.

Comment: it's probably meant to be provided by some other part of the OE build system. It's definitely *not* looking for the version from some BioPerl module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is quite old but I've been running into the same thing.

`create_wrapper(`) is a function in the oe-meta utils.bbclass.

I'm using MontaVista with an updated perl recipe and added the create_wrapper() function to my utils.bbclass from the oe-meta utils.bbclass